# How to get Node.js app running on Azure App Service?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to run the simplest of node.js apps on a Azure App Service (Linux) but I'm out of idéas on how to get this running. I've been trying different approaches and nothing seems to work.

I'm simply deploying the app through FTP and putting the files under "wwwroot" but when requesting the url it loads forever and then ends up with a service unavailable response.

When creating the app I choose Linux as platform, runtime node.js 8.11 and deploy through "code" and not docker.

In the logs I can see this:

```
docker run -d -p 46852:8080 --name [appname] -e WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION=8.11 -e APPSETTING_WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION=8.11 -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=[appname] -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=[id] -e HTTP_LOGGING_ENABLED=1 appsvc/node:8.11.2_1805212105

Container [appname] for site [appname] did not start within expected time limit. Elapsed time = 230.4882261 sec
```

What does this mean, is docker being used somehow even though I setup the app with deploy through "Code" and FTP.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "x",
  "author": "x",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.3"
  }
}
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
const host = process.env.HOST || '127.0.0.1'

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello!'))

app.listen(port, host)
```

I've also tried ssh into the app and running `npm install`. I've tried running the app through ssh console `node server.js` but ends up with the message "Port already in use". I've tried setting the port to 8080 in "application settings" in Azure Portal.

What am I missing here? How do I get the app running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my site, I just did `app.listen(process.env.port);` - without the host argument. And try doing `npm start`.

Also check `web.config` and `iisnode.yml` which are generated automatically and are both necessary to run Node.

Comment: Will try it without host. Is the web.config and iisnode.yml stil valid when running Azure App Service on _Linux_? I don't see any autogenerated files for that in wwwroot.

Comment: Just removing the host did the trick. I owe you a beer Makoto!

Comment: @RikardAskelöf Glad it worked. I didn't realize Linux didn't create those files; I suppose its just Windows services then.

Comment: @RikardAskelöf - No they're not required on linux, I deployed via VS Code extensions and none of those files were created and everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

First off, it would be good to know how exactly are you creating your application (tools used, steps taken etc.). Overall, the main thing to understand - Azure App Service does not use Node.js by default, i.e. once you provisioned it. To specify that the host will be running Node app, you need to set 'WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION' parameter (in Application Settings blade in Azure App Service). Once done, you can deploy with any available option (using publish functionality, local git, using Azure DevOps etc.).
[Here is a good topic to start with](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-nodejs). 
Getting straight to the point:

- Install Azure CLI
- Login to Azure (az login)
- az account show (to see if you're under the right subscription, in case if you have many). Use 'az account set ' to switch if necessary
- Then, according to this instruction, create a resource group, service plan and the web app. Set Node.js runtime
- Compress your app (as per instruction, using either Bash or PS)
- In the App Service, deploy you app (zipped) using Kudu console (Development tools -> Advanced Tools blade, choose Tools -> Zip Push Deploy from the drop down menu)
- Review the results.

Comment: I'm running this on Azure App Service on _Linux_ and I have been using this document as reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/quickstart-nodejs and I wanted to deploy the app just moving the files over FTP. But maybe that is'nt possible? Is Azure CLI is required? The app only consist of these two files (package.json and server.js) and there's no magic in creating the app. I tried putting WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION = 8.11 but stil same error.

Comment: Well, Azure CLI is not a mandatory pre-requisite, that's for sure. I'm offering you this way of deployment just for the clarity sake. If it works, it'd be easier to triage the issue. In fact, not all Node versions are available in App Service and when you enter a parameter (WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION) Azure won't validate it if the version is wrong, but Azure CLI will. I have it set to 10.6.0