# Determine if Nodejs app is running in azure or not

Tags: node.js, azure

In my Nodejs application, want to load env config file for jest based on environment.
How to check NodeJS application running in Azure Environment so that I can load the related env config file.
Thanks.

Comment: check `process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"` if you get true, then you are running inside Azure environment. Also make sure you are not setting `NODE_ENV` yourself using any configuration file used by Azure. The default value is `production`

Comment: @AmirSaleem the problem is, I am already setting the NODE_ENV  variable. Any other idea?

Comment: If you are already setting NODE_ENV, then the problem is solved. you can write configs based on NODE_ENV, so if env is test, set it to something like TEST. What's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check your Kudu or App service editor `(https://<app-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net)` to

1. check the Nodejs app deployed or not
2. check the logs
3. Check the process as well to know whether the App is running or not.

`app.listen(process.env.port);` - without the host argument. And try doing `npm start`.

Also check `web.config` and `iisnode.yml` which are generated automatically and are both necessary to run Node.

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52595401/how-to-get-node-js-app-running-on-azure-app-service/52596634)